# Segmentation Fault with fget()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hi i got a programm that looks like this :

```
FILE* openFile (char* name) {
    FILE *datei = NULL;
    if ((datei=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    return datei;
}


int getFLoatsFromFile(char *dateiName, float **retVal) {
    FILE *datei = openFile("findMaxOfFloats.txt");
    printf("Nice!\n");
    if (datei = NULL) return 1;
    char buffer[256];
    int anzahlzahlen=0;
    while (fgets(buffer,256,datei)!=NULL)   
     {
        float temp;
        sscanf(buffer,"%f\n",&temp);
         *retVal = (float*) realloc(*retVal, (anzahlzahlen+1)*sizeof(float));
            (*retVal)[anzahlzahlen]= temp;
        anzahlzahlen++;
    }
    fclose(datei);  
    return anzahlzahlen;
}
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float *numbers;
    char* dateiname;
    if (argc <2){
        printf("The number of arguments is %d\n", argc);
        dateiname = "findMaxOfFloats.txt";
    }
    else {
        dateiname = argv[1]; 
    }
    float *floatArray = NULL;
    int anz = getFLoatsFromFile(dateiname,&floatArray);
    int size = sizeof(floatArray)/sizeof(floatArray[0]);
    float tempFloat=-FLT_MAX;
    int z;
    for (z= 0; z<size ; z++) {
        if (floatArray[z]>tempFloat) {
            tempFloat = floatArray[z];
        }
    }
    printf("%f",tempFloat);
   }
```

which results in a Segmentation Fault (core dumped). I tried to debug it with gdb with backtrace, and this shows up

```
#0  _IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffdb90 "", n=256, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:47
#1  0x00000000004008b4 in getFLoatsFromFile (
    dateiName=0x400a71 "findMaxOfFloats.txt", retVal=0x7fffffffdcd8)
    at 1-3.c:24
#2  0x0000000000400951 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffddd8) at 1-3.c:46
```

I am new to C so i dont really understand what this means, can some one explain ?

Comment: `if (datei = NULL) return 1;` You assign a null pointer to `datei` here. The expression is false of course, and you end up using a NULL pointer with `fgets`. You probably meant `==`

Comment: `if (datei = NULL)` and various others: you may want to turn on *all* warnings and fix those before proceeding.

Comment: wow just a simple "=" missing and it took me 1 day ! Thank you!

Comment: @Evert May i ask you what are those other issues ? I am programming on linux without an IDE ..

Comment: How can you figure it out so fast, does the stack trace help ? I really wanna understand what it means.

Comment: Also `int size = sizeof(floatArray)/sizeof(floatArray[0]);` --> `int size = anz;`, `if (datei = NULL) return 1;` --> `if (datei == NULL) return 0;`, `FILE *datei = openFile("findMaxOfFloats.txt");` --> `FILE *datei = openFile(dateiName);`

Comment: I figured it out fast because you told us where the problem was, the call to `fgets`. Then it was a matter of examining closely the path of each and every argument from their initialization to the call. A bit of experience (as well as having made the same mistake numerous times when learning to program myself) does help though :)

Comment: @TuấnPhạm The mistake you made is an extremely common one. People who've been here a while have seen it hundreds of time and become good at noticing it.

Comment: And the stack trace is quite informative, seeing as you asked. I didn't look at it too closely when trying to find the mistake, but I did now. Take notice that it says `fp=0x0`. `fp` is the file pointer you passed. It's set to zero, a very (some would even say most) common bitwise representation of a NULL pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah i noticed that the address was a little bit funny but didnt know :) Ty